# Flask-admin create a button next to a text field

Tags: python, flask-admin

I've made a simple form using Flask-admin that looks like the following. I'm now looking into creating a refresh button next to the API text field, but don't really now how to.

Is this called a widget or inline model? I haven't been able to find a button in WTForms either that I can use. Would appreciate any examples on this as I've been able to override textfields, but not place other elements next to it in a easy way.

[image]
    class AdministratorView(sqla.ModelView):
    page_size = 10

```
column_searchable_list = (
    'username',
    'description'
)

column_list = (
    'username',
    'apikey',
    'description',
    'active'
)

column_exclude_list = list = (
    'apikey',
    'auth_type'
)

form_excluded_columns = (
    'auth_type',
    'photos'
)

column_labels = {
    'apikey': 'API Key'
}

form_widget_args = {
        'apikey':{
            'readonly':True
        }
}

form_create_rules = (
    rules.FieldSet(('username', 'password', 'description'), 'Personal'),
    rules.FieldSet(('roles', 'apikey', 'active'), 'Permission'),
)

form_edit_rules = (
    rules.FieldSet(('username', 'description'), 'Personal'),
    rules.FieldSet(('roles', 'apikey', 'active'), 'Permission'),
    rules.Header('Reset password'),
    rules.Field('new_password')
)

def get_create_form(self):
    form = self.scaffold_form()
    form.username = fields.StringField('Username', [validators.Required()])
    form.password = fields.PasswordField('Password', [validators.Required()])
    return form

def get_edit_form(self):
    form = self.scaffold_form()
    delattr(form, 'password')
    form.new_password = fields.PasswordField('New Password')
    return form

def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
    if is_created is False:
        if form.new_password.data:
            model.password = generate_password_hash(form.new_password.data)

def is_accessible(self):
    if login.current_user.is_authenticated:
        return login.current_user.has_role('admin')
```

**Edit:** I'm able to add a new element such as a header/h1 adding a html file like this:

```
{% extends 'admin/model/edit.html' %} 
{% block body %} 
    <h1>My custom header</h1> 
    {{ super() }} 
{% endblock %}
```

However, I can't figure out how to make changes to particular fields in the rendered form. Looking at the edit.html all I can see is the following. How do I "get inside" the rendered_form and add my custom button?

```
{% block edit_form %}
    {{ lib.render_form(form, return_url, extra(), form_opts) }}
  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Rather than using a screenshot, please paste your code into the question properly so that it can be indexed, searched for, read by screen reader users and, if necessary, copied for modification and testing in order to provide an answer.

Comment: To add an additional button to your admin template you will need to override the default template and add your button in the inherited template. Have a look at https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.4/templates/

Comment: Is it possible to create an override for one single field? Looks overkill to override both edit and create.html.

Comment: You don't have to create a template override for each (edit and create). Just create a customized template (e.g. 'admin/edit_user.html') for one of them and use Jinjas template inheritance via `{% extends 'admin/edit_user.html' %}` for the other one.

Comment: I get the concept of creating a block of html and extending the master layout, but have no idea on getting it to show up next to a specific field since it's dynamically created by flask-admin... in my case the apikey text field. The closest I get is for example adding a h1 element before the form, but not change anything in the form itself... added the snippet to my first post.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `lib.render_form_fields` function to render your normal fields and add the button where you want it. You can use `render_form_fields` with multiple fields so you don't need to rewrite the whole template.
Here is a modified version of *flask-admins* [layout_bootstrap3](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/tree/master/examples/layout_bootstrap3) example that places a button close to the name field:

```py
{% extends 'admin/model/edit.html' %}

{% block brand %}
    <h2 id="brand">Edit {{ admin_view.name|capitalize }}</h2>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <hr>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  {% call lib.form_tag(form) %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        {{ lib.render_form_fields([form.name])}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Testbutton</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        {{ lib.render_form_fields([form.email])}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-buttons">
      {{ lib.render_form_buttons(return_url) }}
    </div>
  {% endcall %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `form_edit_rules` on your custom view to add HTML using the `rules.HTML` rule.

eg:

```
form_edit_rules = (
    rules.FieldSet(('username', 'description'), 'Personal'),
    rules.FieldSet(('roles', 'apikey', 'active'), 'Permission'),
    rules.HTML('<button onclick="alert('hello')">Refresh</button>'),
    rules.Header('Reset password'),
    rules.Field('new_password')
)
```