# add buttons that populate other fields in built-in templates of Flask-Admin

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I would like to add a button to my Flask-Admin create view, and following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40765490/flask-admin-create-a-button-next-to-a-text-field) I managed to do so.

Now, assuming that the model passed to that view, say `User` has:

- A *one to many* relationship with `ClassA` and `ClassB`
- `ClassA` has also a *one to many* relationship with `ClassB`

And assuming that in my create view I've added some instance of `ClassA` when creating an instance of `User`, say `my_class_a_instance`, I would like that this button:

- performs a query on `my_class_a_instance`, returning any instances of `ClassB` (or `my_class_b_instance`s) related at that moment with it
- populates the `form.class_b` field in the create template with those results
- if possible, pop up some modal window promting the user for confirmation. Possible with [`@action`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921400/flask-admin-extend-with-select-dropdown-menu-with-custom-button)

My approach so far goes like this:

```
# templates/admin/cascade_button_create.html

{% extends 'admin/model/create.html' %}

{% block body %}

{% call lib.form_tag(form) %}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xg-10">
    {{ lib.render_form_fields([form.name])}}
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xg-10">
        <!-- form.cities follows the attributes of sqla model -->
      {{ lib.render_form_fields([form.instances_of_a])}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-xg-2">
        <!-- so this button should query any model related to form.cities 
        and populate the create form with whatever comes out.

        Say Street has a one to many relationship, I want this 
        button to run some method of the form get_instances_of_b_from_instance_of_a(form.instances_of_a) (query_method() for short) that fills
        the field form.instances_of_b

        If possible I would like to pop up a modal window prompting the user
        to confirm this before filling this field.-->
      <a href="{{ query_method() }}" class="btn btn-default">Add with cascade</a>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-buttons">
  {{ lib.render_form_buttons(return_url) }}
</div>
{% endcall %}
{% endblock %}-
```

I would be registering this view like the documentation says

```
# admin/views.py

class CascadesView(ModelView):

    create_template = 'admin/cascade_button_create.html'
```

I haven't found information on this, and the templates don't have many comments that help.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I've copied the examples from the `flask-admin` repo and set mine in https://github.com/diegoquintanav/flask-admin-autopopulate to play with

Comment: I think you should start by looking at the [flask ajax functionality](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.form_ajax_refs). If you want, put a complete minimal example on github or here, and I'll give it a shot, because I think it's an interesting question.

Comment: At the moment I don't have a minimal example, sorry. I can't manage to get it working. I will try what you mention and expect to come back later with a better example. The example now works on the bootstrap example of the Flask-Admin repo as shown in the SO question I've posted as reference, and it only shows a button that does nothing.

Comment: @Joost I've added a repo if you want to give it a shot. I will be also working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked a bit further into it, and this seems very specific behavior, which is not implemented in flask-admin. I went ahead and had a look at it anyways, and the only way I could think of to easily do this is by using Ajax and a special api route.

So I've added this to your js:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" onClick="retrieve_location_b_ids()">Add with cascade</a>
<script>
function retrieve_location_b_ids(){

  // make sure that the user wants to preload the b locations
  if (confirm('load location b connected to location a?')){
    // look for the selected options
    var selected_a_locations = $('#s2id_sub_locations_a').select2("val");

    // request the b_ids using the a_ids provided by the user using ajax
    var oData = new FormData();
    oData.append('selected_a_locations', JSON.stringify(selected_a_locations));
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("POST", "{{url_for('look_up_b_locations_connected_to_a_locations')}}", true);
    oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
      if (oReq.status == 200) {
        // get the correct b ids back from the ajax request, and use them to load the select2 field
        var selected_b_ids_list = JSON.parse(oReq.responseText)
        $('#s2id_sub_locations_b').select2('val', selected_b_ids_list);
      } else {
        alert("Error " + oReq.status + " occurred when retrieving the ids")
      }
    };
    oReq.send(oData);
  }
}

</script>
```

and the flask route which deals with this request:

```
@app.route('/api/look_up_b_locations_connected_to_a_locations', methods=['POST'])
def look_up_b_locations_connected_to_a_locations():
    # use a set in case the same b location is in multiple a locations to prevent duplicates
    b_location_set = set()
    a_location_list = json.loads(request.form['selected_a_locations'])
    for a_location_id in a_location_list:
        a_location = SubLocationA.query.get_or_404(a_location_id)
        for b_location in a_location.sub_sub_locations_b:
            b_location_set.add(str(b_location.id))
    return jsonify(list(b_location_set))
```

It seems to work pretty well, and deals with most edge cases (I hope).

Comment: this works! The only line I don't understand is `var selected_a_locations = $('#s2id_sub_locations_a').select2("val");`

Is this some specific syntax of https://select2.org? If so, what does `#s2id_sub_locations_a` refer to?

Comment: Yeah, it's select2 syntax. I also had to look it up because I've never heard of it before. `#s2id_sub_locations_a` is the id flask admin gives the field in your DOM. You need this id in order to find out which values where selected. I found it to be this specific value by using inspect element in my browser.

Comment: that is a rather specific behaviour indeed. Thanks again! I've commented your PR so please check it.